# Prove that the function $u= \|x\|{_{2}^{2-n}} $ has $\Delta u = 0 $?

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have been trying to solve this for hours but without success. I tried to write down the definitions which means that our function can also be written as

$$u= \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} |x_{j}|^{2}}{\sqrt{ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} |x_{j}|^{2} \right)^{n}}}$$

and then we have defined 
$$\Delta u = \nabla \cdot (\nabla u) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial ^{2}\|x\|_{2}^{2-n}}{\partial x{_{i}}^{2}}$$

Now here I am totally stuck. If somebody could help me I would be very thankful

Comment: The first step is to do the actual calculation. You have $Y = \|x\|_2^{2-n} = (x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2)^{\frac{2-n}{2}}$ which allows you to compute the derivatives $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x_i}$ and  $\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial x_i^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x_i}$ and use this to evaluate $\Delta u = \sum \frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial x_i^2}$. The result will simplify greatly (you should get $0$ for $x\not = 0$).